# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element '...'

Tags: xml, xsd

My XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xsd:simpleType name="Letter">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="^[A-Za-z]?$" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:element name="Test" type="Letter" />
</xsd:schema>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Letter>A</Letter>
```

Any ideas?

Here's the website I'm using:

http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared an element `Test` of type `Letter`.  The XML should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>A</Test>
```